# Laravel Multiple Relationship for a sum column

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I have Three Models name Invoices, Invoiceitems and Products.

Each Invoices HasMany Relationship with Invoiceitems Model.

Each Invoiceitems HasOne Relationship with Products Model.

I need to sum of Invoiceitem product amount where the Product has category 4.

**Table Structure**

**Invoice**

id | date | total_amt

**Invoiceitem**

id | invoiceid | product_id | product_amt | quantity | total_amt

**Product**

id | product_name | category_id

**Relationship**

**Invoice Model**

```
public function invoiceitems()
{

  return $this->hasMany('App\Invoiceitems', 'invoiceid', 'id');

}
```

**Invoiceitem Model**

```
public function products()
{

  return $this->hasOne('App\Products', 'id', 'product_id');

}
```

**Expected Report**

Invoice No | Date | Veg Category Product Amt | NonVeg Category Product Amt | Total Amt

KL0001 | 15-05-2021 | 0.00 | 190.366 | 190.366

KL0002 | 16-05-2021 | 20.00 | 350.000 | 370.000

Currently we use following Helper Function to get Particular category Products Total Amount

```
function getInvdiscsumamt($inv_id, $prdtype)
{

    $totaldisamt = Invoiceitems::Where('invoice_id', $inv_id)->whereHas('products', function ($query) use ($prdtype) {

        $query->where('category_id', $prdtype);

    })->sum('total_amt');

    return $totalpdtamt;
}
```

How to display particular category products total amount using Elequoent method

Answer (score 0):

You can try one of the aggregate functions that already exist in Eloquent, see https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#other-aggregate-functions, for instance `withSum`:

```php
$invoiceItem = InvoiceItem::query()
    ->where('invoice_id', $invId)
    ->withSum(['products', function($query) use ($productType) {
        $query->where('category_id', $productType);
    }, 'frequency'])
    ->first();
```

Your property will then be available using the property `{relation}_{function}_{column}`, so in this case `products_sum_frequency`.

Note that the `withSum` does not share anything with the `with` (or `whereHas`) function, that means that if you use a subselection in your query like `->with(['products', function($query){...}])` that will be a separate selection from the `withSum` query.

I also recommend to use proper camelcasing in your functions and also your models. I'd also use singular names for all your model class names. So `Invoiceitems` would become `InvoiceItem` (`models/InvoiceItem.php`). This is the default way to define it in laravel as far as I'm aware.